# How to customize CQ search that returns results based on keyword entered

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have a requirement where I enter some text say "samsung" in the search box of a custom search component, and it has to return all the node names under /etc which have "samsung" text in its nodename. For example, it should return Samsung Galaxy S4, Samsung Galaxy S5 as results. I guess, I need to use QueryBuilder API to achieve such a requirement, but if anybody have implemented such kind of requirement earlier, please share your inputs here.

Comment: people who downvoted, can you please care to explain why you have downvoted? If I am not clear with the question, I can elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use QueryBuilder to achieve it and going through [the docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) would itself provide you the code for a sample implementation.

However, the sample query would be

```
path=/etc
nodename=*samsung*
p.limit=-1
```